# Create date object to use in Calendar Plugin in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am using the Calendar Plugin for Ionic 2 (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/calendar/).

To create a new event I use:

```
createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate)
```

Where startDate is of type Date.
I have a string with the startdate:

```
date = '2017-02-02 15:36:00'
```

How can I convert this to use as startDate?

I tried:

```
var startDate = Date.parse(date);
```

But Sublime tells me that this is not the type it is expecting.

My complete code looks like this:

```
var startDate = Date.parse('2017-01-01 12:00:00');
Calendar.createEvent('Name', '', '', startDate, startDate).then(
                  (msg) => { },
                  (err) => { } 
                );
```

The error I get:

> Typescript Error Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Date'.

Comment: do u get any errors using the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because Date.parse returns a number and not a Date.

I have accomplished creating a Calendar event by using Moment.

You can install this package by using the command `npm install moment --save` and `npm install @types/moment --save-dev` and importing it in your class with this import: `import * as moment from 'moment';`.

The following code can be used to create your Date object:

`let startDate = moment('2017-02-02 15:36:00').toDate();`

Try making the event with that Date, worked for me :)